# Failed to install Locustio on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, pip

I'm trying to install [locustio](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/installation.html) on Ubuntu 18.04.1, using

```
pip install locustio
```

I don't get any errors during the installation or after it is completed, however when I try to run

```
locust --version
```

or

```
locust --help
```

I get `locust: command not found`

I don't understand what I did wrong and why it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try to call it with full path - something like `/usr/local/bin/locust --version`. Also check [official quickstart guide](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) for details and creating locusfile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and think it more has to do with how you run the program on Ubuntu. There is probably a way to add it to the path but I don't know how.

Try `python3 -m locust.main ...` and see if that helps at all. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**here's a trick:**

1. write this command `pip uninstall locustio` in the console
2. this is what will be returned in the console

   `Uninstalling locustio-0.12.2:
     Would remove:
       /home/elta/.local/bin/locust
       /home/elta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locust/*
       /home/elta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locustio-0.12.2.dist-info/*
   Proceed (y/n)?`
3. write `n` , and copy the first directory which would be in my case
   `/home/elta/.local/bin/locust`
4. now this is the directory you gonna use every time to call locust command, for example

`/home/elta/.local/bin/locust --version`

.... not the best solution, but it works perfectly and did the trick